# How to delete all the public ip addresses in a Resource group in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I want to delete all the public ip addresses in a resource group in Azure using single command rather than doing it one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following Powershell scripts to achieve your requirement:

```
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName <yourresourcegroupname> | Remove-AzureRmPublicIpAddress
```

Also, you can use the command `Force`  to run without asking for user confirmation:

```
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName <yourresourcegroupname> | Remove-AzureRmPublicIpAddress  -Force
```

I test in my lab and succeed.

Comment: Its working but it prompts me for every ip to be deleted. Is their any way to skip this prompt and it should work automatically

Comment: @Vatan Bansal .Of course you can achieve that. We can just add `- Force` at the end .